# A return nested inside a Parse.com afterSave

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

As I understand it in afterSave, there is no "response". Further, in afterSave, you don't "return".

Given that, notice the following code I found from a colleague. Notice that colleague, "returned" the company.save, inside the query.

```
   return company.save();
```

**It seems wrong**. But am I missing something there? Is there some reason one SHOULD return from inside the nested success function there?  Something obvious I'm missing or don't know about?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("TableName", function(request)
 {
 var mysteryState = request.object.get("state");
 var club = request.object.get("club");

 if (mysteryState == "specialState")
  {
  console.log(">>> specialState handling." );

  var query = new Parse.Query("Members");
  query.equalTo("club", club);

  query.count({
  success: function(count)
   {
   club.set("nb",count);

   Parse.Cloud.run("doSomeLongThing",{blah:blah});
   console.log(">>> ran long process in the nested query in afterSave");

   // mystery code: is it just wrong?
   ////////return company.save();

   // works fine as you'd expect:
   company.save();

   },

  error: function(error){...}

  });
  }
});
```

Comment: Probably he's used to code with promises. It's good practise to always `return` a value from a function :-)

Comment: thanks for that input, Bergi!  you really think it's good practice to always return a value from a function?  in the Parse universe, everything such as "afterSave" has no return right ??

Comment: Yes, even if the return value of the callback is ignored, you still might `return` it. Maybe the function gets used elsewhere (or your code is rewritten) and there the return value is used. Especially if you are using promises with Parse, this seems probable.

Comment: Have you asked your colleague? You should absolutely do - maybe update (or answer) your question with what he said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The afterSave hook doesn't have a response object and there is no reason try to return anything.

Returning could be useful in other cloud code to pass a promise to the calling function, but this case is irrelevant in an afterSave hook as there is no calling function. Calling `company.save()` [will return a promise](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#save), and since you are not able to return anything from an afterSave hook, it is useless.

With respect to what Bergi has mentioned, it's impossible that a callback is being ignored because there is no callback. There is no way that the afterSave hook is being used elsewhere in Parse's cloud code and the return statement is meaningless.

[Reference](https://parse.com/questions/cloud-code-unsaved-user-error-on-aftersave-function)

Comment: outstanding explanation !

Comment: Sorry forgot to Tick you until now, Russell.  Thanks again